# Error when install nodejs with sequelize on centos

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is my version of nodejs: 6.17.1 and sequelize 6.4.0. I folow this: https://bezkoder.com/react-node-express-mysql/. And I got error:

```
> /app/nodejs/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:277
>       ...options

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
>     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/nodejs/node_modules/sequelize/index.js:8:18)
```

So am  I wrong something ?

Solved with this code:

```
+ sudo yum install nodejs
+ node --version
+ npm --version
+ which node
+ which npm
+ curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
+ ls -la /etc/yum.repos.d/|grep nodesource
+ sudo yum remove -y nodejs npm
+ sudo yum list available nodejs
+ sudo yum install nodejs
+ node --version
+ npm --version
```

Credit: https://matthiashoys.wordpress.com/2020/01/15/how-to-upgrade-node-js-from-v6-to-v12-on-centos-linux-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator (...) is not supported by your node version. You need version above 8.6.

follow this link, to find out specific support methods in node, https://node.green/#ES2015

Comment: Thank you, follow your hint. I make this code and done.
+ sudo yum install nodejs
+ node --version
+ npm --version
+ which node
+ which npm
+ curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
+ ls -la /etc/yum.repos.d/|grep nodesource
+ sudo yum remove -y nodejs npm
+ sudo yum list available nodejs
+ sudo yum install nodejs
+ node --version
+ npm --version
Credit: https://matthiashoys.wordpress.com/2020/01/15/how-to-upgrade-node-js-from-v6-to-v12-on-centos-linux-7/